# Getting Runtime Exception with custom SeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar, runtimeexception

I tried to add a nice custom seekbar to my android project.
I used [this](http://developer-dot-android.blogspot.hu/2012/03/custom-seekbar-tutorial.html) and [this](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/) tutorial and I got the very same exception. I don't think both of the tutorials are wrong... What can be my mistake ?

My xml files:

**seekbar_progress_bg.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <clip >
            <bitmap
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:antialias="true"
                android:dither="false"
                android:filter="false"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/green">
             </bitmap>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**seekbar_progress.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
         <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:dither="true"
            android:src="@drawable/whitepatch">
          </nine-patch>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
           <clip >
               <shape >
                  <gradient
                    android:angle="270"
                    android:centerColor="#80127fb1"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a004638f"
                    android:startColor="#80028ac8">
                   </gradient>
              </shape>
           </clip>
     </item>
     <item
             android:id="@android:id/progress"
             android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress_bg">
     </item>
</layer-list>
```

And my seekbar:

```
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/pagesSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/shine_btn" 

        android:maxHeight="9dp"
        android:minHeight="9dp"/>
```

See my logcat here:

```
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.myproject/com.mypackage.myproject.reader.Reader}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class android.widget.SeekBar
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class android.widget.SeekBar
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at com.mypackage.myproject.reader.Reader.onCreate(Reader.java:87)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     ... 11 more
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     ... 23 more
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/seekbar_progress.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02002f
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:179)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.<init>(AbsSeekBar.java:61)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:81)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.widget.SeekBar.<init>(SeekBar.java:77)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     ... 26 more
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #5: <nine-patch> requires a valid 9-patch source image
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.inflate(NinePatchDrawable.java:267)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:154)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
07-31 13:25:11.996: E/AndroidRuntime(5124):     ... 31 more
```

In the graphical layout I can clearly see my new skin on the seekbar but when I try to run the app it is just crashes.

Please help me what m i doing wrong?

Comment: your tutorial-links are not included above!

Comment: Also you might want to show us seekbar_progress.xml!